# Finiteness of the Riesz potential of the Hausdorff measure restricted to a compact set

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, potential-theory, hausdorff-measure

If $E$ is compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0<
  H^s(E)<\infty$, where $H^s$ is $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure
  and $0<s<n$, then fix $x$ and define $$ m(r):=
  f(B(x,r)) :=H^s(E\cap B(x,r))$$

If $m(r)\leq r^s$, then $$
  \int_{B(x,1)} \frac{df(y)}{|x-y|^t} <\infty$$ for $0<t<
  s$.

Proof of special case: If $m(r)=r^s$, then it is trivial.

How can we prove this in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Layer cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation):

$$|x-y|^{-t} = \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{y : |x-y|^{-t} > \lambda\}} \,d\lambda = \int_0^\infty \chi_{B(x, \lambda^{-1/t})} \,d\lambda $$
Integrate both sides with respect to restricted Hausdorff measure $\mu=H^s_{|E}$, changing the order of integration on the right (Tonelli's theorem)
$$\int |x-y|^{-t} \,d\mu(y) =  \int_0^\infty \mu(B(x, \lambda^{-1/t})) \,d\lambda  $$
By assumption,
$$\mu(B(x, \lambda^{-1/t})) \le \min(\lambda^{-s/t}, H^s(E))$$ and the integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty \min(\lambda^{-s/t}, H^s(E)) \,d\lambda  $$
converges because $s/t > 1$.